# ClientSecret in appsettings.json with IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm trying to get IdentityServer4 working with appsettings.json specifying a client secret for hybrid grant type.

The end of [this article](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/clients.html) says that I need to sha256 hash and then base64 encode the secret if I want to put it in appsettings.json. So take the secret "secret" and put it through https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html gets "2bb80d537b1da3e38bd30361aa855686bde0eacd7162fef6a25fe97bf527a25b" which base64 encoded is "MmJiODBkNTM3YjFkYTNlMzhiZDMwMzYxYWE4NTU2ODZiZGUwZWFjZDcxNjJmZWY2YTI1ZmU5N2JmNTI3YTI1Yg==". That makes my appsettings.json for the mvc client look like this

```
{
    ...
    "ClientSecrets": [ { 
        "Value": "MkJCODBENTM3QjFEQTNFMzhCRDMwMzYxQUE4NTU2ODZCREUwRUFDRDcxNjJGRUY2QTI1RkU5N0JGNTI3QTI1Qg=="
    } ],
    ...
}
```

On the MVC client, the config looks like this

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Authority = Configuration["OpenIdConnectAuthority"];

    options.ClientId = "xxx-mvc";
    options.ClientSecret = "secret";

    options.RemoteAuthenticationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
    options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = !Environment.IsDevelopment();
    options.Scope.Clear();
    options.Scope.Add("openid profile");

    options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-callback-oidc");
    options.SignedOutCallbackPath = new PathString("/signout-callback-oidc");
    options.SignedOutRedirectUri = new PathString("/");
    options.ClaimsIssuer = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name
    };
})
```

Despite this seemingly being correct, the identity server logs have

```
fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.ClientSecretValidator[0]
      Client secret validation failed for client: xxx-mvc.
```

If I remove a portion of the base64 secret, identity server logs

`Secret: no description uses invalid hashing algorithm.`

So I know that the appsettings.json client secret is being picked up. If I comment out `options.ClientSecret = "secret";` on the mvc side, identity server logs `Hashed shared secret validator cannot process NoSecret` so I know that config is being picked up.

How do I specify the correct two strings to get the secret "secret" to work in this situation?

Full logs from identity server are:

```
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Request path /.well-known/openid-configuration matched to endpoint type Discovery
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Endpoint enabled: Discovery, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration
trce: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint[0]
      Processing discovery request.
dbug: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint[0]
      Start discovery request
trce: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint[0]
      Calling into discovery response generator: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.DiscoveryResponseGenerator
trce: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking result: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.Results.DiscoveryDocumentResult
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Request path /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks matched to endpoint type Discovery
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Endpoint enabled: Discovery, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryKeyEndpoint
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryKeyEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks
trce: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryKeyEndpoint[0]
      Processing discovery request.
dbug: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryKeyEndpoint[0]
      Start key discovery request
trce: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryKeyEndpoint[0]
      Calling into discovery response generator: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.DiscoveryResponseGenerator
trce: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking result: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.Results.JsonWebKeysResult
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Request path /connect/authorize matched to endpoint type Authorize
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Endpoint enabled: Authorize, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint for /connect/authorize
dbug: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      Start authorize request
dbug: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      User in authorize request: 3a28f734-5d49-49e0-a28c-c851adfb4bf6
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator[0]
      Start authorize request protocol validation
trce: IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore[0]
      Calling into client configuration validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultClientConfigurationValidator
dbug: IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore[0]
      client configuration validation for client xxx-mvc succeeded.
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator[0]
      Checking for PKCE parameters
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator[0]
      No PKCE used.
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator[0]
      Calling into custom validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
trce: IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator[0]
      Authorize request protocol validation successful
dbug: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      ValidatedAuthorizeRequest
      {
        "ClientId": "xxx-mvc",
        "ClientName": "xxx MVC Client",
        "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:4500/signin-callback-oidc",
        "AllowedRedirectUris": [
          "http://localhost:4500/signin-callback-oidc"
        ],
        "SubjectId": "3a28f734-5d49-49e0-a28c-c851adfb4bf6",
        "ResponseType": "code id_token",
        "ResponseMode": "form_post",
        "GrantType": "hybrid",
        "RequestedScopes": "openid profile",
        "State": "CfDJ8BvOOrOwFENEmcvniNGXxvPnb1gKLB_qQdpSkS5FI88I3vvopAgk9v23GYrBOce_S5PeDsBUzYEj28zpC__y1Q8ZcU2LE9vf7x9pBvmqltXBBdp4zRbhV52iiTEtfpj-MyvDrMTUWR1jCx_b4CmdObvZdVdqf3KvUKO6dCJvPVP5G0OBG6jkuWUvsQnm8uUTE28XBrhwMIn_3D1ns2BgShqtV6j9G7HzatthP-yg9tDV198xILScflYHAgNPWGiJUZcZoar1_FSi9ynxlJSonnkuAw6epwPYk1lvIKZrK5ofTHizmOBUHI_b-xyVXIzoQw",
        "Nonce": "637027688717360370.ODBiYTgwZGMtNjRhYy00NmE4LWI3MDAtYWY4MTcxMmNkMmNjYmYwYjY1ZDUtMTUyYy00YjFlLWE2ZmMtNTdkM2YzMDY3NTAy",
        "SessionId": "3b0abfecf91a43a58e3f24ccb6ff1351",
        "Raw": {
          "client_id": "xxx-mvc",
          "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:4500/signin-callback-oidc",
          "response_type": "code id_token",
          "scope": "openid profile",
          "response_mode": "form_post",
          "nonce": "637027688717360370.ODBiYTgwZGMtNjRhYy00NmE4LWI3MDAtYWY4MTcxMmNkMmNjYmYwYjY1ZDUtMTUyYy00YjFlLWE2ZmMtNTdkM2YzMDY3NTAy",
          "state": "CfDJ8BvOOrOwFENEmcvniNGXxvPnb1gKLB_qQdpSkS5FI88I3vvopAgk9v23GYrBOce_S5PeDsBUzYEj28zpC__y1Q8ZcU2LE9vf7x9pBvmqltXBBdp4zRbhV52iiTEtfpj-MyvDrMTUWR1jCx_b4CmdObvZdVdqf3KvUKO6dCJvPVP5G0OBG6jkuWUvsQnm8uUTE28XBrhwMIn_3D1ns2BgShqtV6j9G7HzatthP-yg9tDV198xILScflYHAgNPWGiJUZcZoar1_FSi9ynxlJSonnkuAw6epwPYk1lvIKZrK5ofTHizmOBUHI_b-xyVXIzoQw",
          "x-client-SKU": "ID_NETSTANDARD2_0",
          "x-client-ver": "5.3.0.0"
        }
      }
trce: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator[0]
      ProcessInteractionAsync
dbug: IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultConsentService[0]
      Client is configured to not require consent, no consent is required
dbug: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeResponseGenerator[0]
      Creating Hybrid Flow response.
dbug: IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.PersistedGrantStore[0]
      GpVcH5oK1O8xEaWazwBmHumW8moTQsBnVATxPiUxIfs= not found in database
dbug: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeResponseGenerator[0]
      Creating Implicit Flow response.
trce: IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultTokenService[0]
      Creating identity token
dbug: IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultClaimsService[0]
      Getting claims for identity token for subject: 3a28f734-5d49-49e0-a28c-c851adfb4bf6 and client: xxx-mvc
dbug: IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultClaimsService[0]
      In addition to an id_token, an access_token was requested. No claims other than sub are included in the id_token. To obtain more user claims, either use the user info endpoint or set AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken on the client configuration.
trce: IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultTokenService[0]
      Creating JWT identity token
trce: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      Identity token issued for xxx-mvc (xxx MVC Client) / 3a28f734-5d49-49e0-a28c-c851adfb4bf6: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ijc3ODc1NWJmMmZkMWRiZWVmNjZkZDdmZjY2YmM5NjBlIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.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.p9LKUCqmK8fjlznJtU5NGgtKE2fsSnxx8EW2ngu2pw-eSJXsuvI7t6FkxlHw6joVG178JXGfMY4BXt83binl9li3NLjzjJC7k8_07QUL_fknYB05rwhfAH995mxqXTV1A5n8ppjXzXcixAkVaA1Cxgb7mvqqfVHqRY2ra-MeIa7Esew5CiTeerlMT87wdWbIMmbK84TGSM26jLN1Uav6YYB-8Lonu2hcS3s4LXLS42bvy04Uc-UUOXcxK0LDgQu-stWfFjr9tYeoIefsgZIOJaEDtgwulExhNWTrPlFF5k9qYyYv4keKM_1dckP47-B4TR5m_1PEzGNeSJb48RwrXQ
trce: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      Code issued for xxx-mvc (xxx MVC Client) / 3a28f734-5d49-49e0-a28c-c851adfb4bf6: 05331f140cb9626a391f6033d1ab6396711b614cdab5f224024336aa94f996f4
dbug: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      Authorize endpoint response
      {
        "SubjectId": "3a28f734-5d49-49e0-a28c-c851adfb4bf6",
        "ClientId": "xxx-mvc",
        "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:4500/signin-callback-oidc",
        "State": "CfDJ8BvOOrOwFENEmcvniNGXxvPnb1gKLB_qQdpSkS5FI88I3vvopAgk9v23GYrBOce_S5PeDsBUzYEj28zpC__y1Q8ZcU2LE9vf7x9pBvmqltXBBdp4zRbhV52iiTEtfpj-MyvDrMTUWR1jCx_b4CmdObvZdVdqf3KvUKO6dCJvPVP5G0OBG6jkuWUvsQnm8uUTE28XBrhwMIn_3D1ns2BgShqtV6j9G7HzatthP-yg9tDV198xILScflYHAgNPWGiJUZcZoar1_FSi9ynxlJSonnkuAw6epwPYk1lvIKZrK5ofTHizmOBUHI_b-xyVXIzoQw",
        "Scope": "openid profile"
      }
trce: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      End authorize request. result type: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.Results.AuthorizeResult
trce: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking result: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.Results.AuthorizeResult
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Request path /connect/token matched to endpoint type Token
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Endpoint enabled: Token, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint for /connect/token
trce: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint[0]
      Processing token request.
dbug: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint[0]
      Start token request.
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.ClientSecretValidator[0]
      Start client validation
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.BasicAuthenticationSecretParser[0]
      Start parsing Basic Authentication secret
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.PostBodySecretParser[0]
      Start parsing for secret in post body
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.SecretParser[0]
      Parser found secret: PostBodySecretParser
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.SecretParser[0]
      Secret id found: xxx-mvc
trce: IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore[0]
      Calling into client configuration validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultClientConfigurationValidator
dbug: IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore[0]
      client configuration validation for client xxx-mvc succeeded.
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.HashedSharedSecretValidator[0]
      No matching hashed secret found.
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.SecretValidator[0]
      Secret validators could not validate secret
fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.ClientSecretValidator[0]
      Client secret validation failed for client: xxx-mvc.
trce: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking result: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.Results.TokenErrorResult
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Identity Server 4's algorithm in [IdentityServer4.Models.HashExtensions](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/44651bea9b02c992902639b21205f433aad47d03/src/IdentityServer4/src/Extensions/HashExtensions.cs) .

In one application run below method :

```
public string Sha256(string input)
{
    using (var sha = SHA256.Create())
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        var hash = sha.ComputeHash(bytes);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
    }
}
```

The result will be `K7gNU3sdo+OL0wNhqoVWhr3g6s1xYv72ol/pe/Unols=` if password is `secret`. Put that value to application.json should work :

```
"ClientSecrets": [ { "Value": "K7gNU3sdo+OL0wNhqoVWhr3g6s1xYv72ol/pe/Unols=" } ],
```

Comment: Interesting, is it because of the UTF8 encoding? Maybe these online generators are using Unicode. Presumably it's safe to commit this hash to source control because there's no way to infer the original client from it?

Comment: IMO , it's better not to upload the secret to source control even you can confirm no leak risk .

Answer (score 6):

Use this website to get base64 encoded sha256 of your secret https://hash.online-convert.com/sha256-generator

It produces the following results for "secret"

```
hex: 2bb80d537b1da3e38bd30361aa855686bde0eacd7162fef6a25fe97bf527a25b
HEX: 2BB80D537B1DA3E38BD30361AA855686BDE0EACD7162FEF6A25FE97BF527A25B
h:e:x: 2b:b8:0d:53:7b:1d:a3:e3:8b:d3:03:61:aa:85:56:86:bd:e0:ea:cd:71:62:fe:f6:a2:5f:e9:7b:f5:27:a2:5b
base64: K7gNU3sdo+OL0wNhqoVWhr3g6s1xYv72ol/pe/Unols=
```

Take the base64 result and put it into appsettings.config

```
"Clients": [
  {
    ...
    "ClientId": "clientId",
    "ClientSecrets": [ { "Value": "K7gNU3sdo+OL0wNhqoVWhr3g6s1xYv72ol/pe/Unols=" } ],
    ...
  },
```

And then in your C#

```
{
      ...
      ClientId = "clientId",
      ClientSecret = "secret",
      ...
 }
```

Works for me

Answer (score 3):

This is very similar to Nan Yu's answer, but if you want a quicker way to generate the hash, it can be accomplished from the terminal:

PowerShell

```
> $secret = "secret"
> $hasher = [System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm]::Create('sha256')
> $hash = $hasher.ComputeHash([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($secret))
> [Convert]::ToBase64String($hash)
K7gNU3sdo+OL0wNhqoVWhr3g6s1xYv72ol/pe/Unols=
```

*nix with openssl

```
$ echo -n 'secret' | openssl dgst -binary -sha256 | openssl base64
K7gNU3sdo+OL0wNhqoVWhr3g6s1xYv72ol/pe/Unols=
```